# Java все об Os вывести на экран

Tags: java, windows

Хочу на Java все об Os вывести на экран. Тоесть:

- Имя
- Архитектура
- Пользователь
- И.Т.Д

ОS Windows если что))

Comment: Лучше это делать на С++ там больше выведешь

Comment: @jeremy228 на чем основано сие заявление?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Некоторые свойства можно вывести так:

```
class SystemProperties {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.getProperties().list(System.out);
    }
}
```

Comment: А как отдельно все это получить?

Answer (score 1):

Я предлагаю вам почитать про Java getProperty(); это функция возвращающая строки.

Подробнее: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Сам когда-то использовал ))